# Print content of a folder with a variable path in BASH

Tags: bash, ls

In my bash script I need to check the content of a folder, but its path can be changed with tree different "endings"

initially my folder is:

```
/home/myuser/my_folder
```

Then a user can modify the name of my folder with tree possibile endings

```
/home/myuser/my_folder_aaaa
/home/myuser/my_folder_bbbb
/home/myuser/my_folder_cccc
```

So, a user can add "_aaaa" or "_bbbb" "_cccc"

These suffixes are known.

In my bash script, how can I check with "ls" the content of my folder also in case someone changes the name? 
N.B: I need to check only this folder, so if there is a folder called "/home/myuser/my_folder_ssss" must not match and content must not be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you need something like this:

```
ls -1 | egrep "^my_folder(|_aaaa|_bbbb|_cccc)$"
```

This command prints the name of the specified folder if it exists.

`ls -1` prints all items names inside the directory one per line.

`egrep` checks if the name of item matches to `my_folder` or `my_folder_aaaa`, `my_folder_bbbb`, `my_folder_cccc`.

Then you can do whatever you want with this name. For example, you can check the contents with:

```
ls -l `ls -1 | egrep "^my_folder(|_aaaa|_bbbb|_cccc)$"`
```

Comment: how can I retrieve the current full path? since i don't know the change made, how can I "save" in a variable the full new path (e.g., /home/myuser/my_folder_bbbb)? I tried to insert the command "pwd" but nothing..

Comment: @user3472065 Please, check this: http://superuser.com/questions/202645/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: Please see: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression predicates in *find* and execute *ls* if the regex matches:

```
find /home/myuser/ -regex ".*/my_folder\(_aaaa\|_bbbb\|_cccc\)$" -exec ls "{}" ";"
```

Comment: One could also use the more verbose approach which is descriped in POSIX find: `find /home/myuser/ \( -name 'my_folder_aaaa' -o -name 'my_folder_bbbb' ... \) -exec ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the folder content, and if the list of known suffixes is not too long, give a try to this:

```
ls -d /home/myuser/my_folder/* /home/myuser/my_folder/.* /home/myuser/my_folder_aaaa/* /home/myuser/my_folder_aaaa/.* /home/myuser/my_folder_bbbb/* /home/myuser/my_folder_bbbb/.* /home/myuser/my_folder_cccc/* /home/myuser/my_folder_cccc/.* 2>/dev/null
```

`-d`: do not list content of directory.

`2>/dev/null`: redirect standard error to `/dev/null`; `ls` error messages about non existing directories won't be displayed.

Note that `find` is preferred in scripts.

Comment: You can also use `setopt -s nullglob` to expand non matching globs to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The following will `ls -l` the folders that match the pattern in your description

```
    ls /home/myuser/my_folder_* | grep "aaaa\|bbbb\|cccc" | while read x; do ls -l ${x:0:-1}; done
```

Comment: Please see: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Yup! parsing `ls` output seems like a bad idea. Thank you.